# Distributed Resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am planning a system that requires collaboration between many local Rails apps.  The design calls for a global app to relay RESTful requests between these servers.

For example, imagine each school having a local Rails app, including a Teacher resource.  I propose a global app which provides access to teachers as: /school/42/teacher/3

The School resource on the global server has a field for the base URL of the app at each school, so it can relay such a request to school_42_url/teacher/3.

The design calls for relaying, rather than having school servers connecting directly to each other.

I can think of several ways to achieve this but, being new to Rails, can't work out which one is 'the Rails way'.

1. ActiveResource is appealing, but seems to require a fixed 'site' rather than setting it for each request.
2. Routing, perhaps with URL globbing might work, but I need to see an example of how to achieve this.
3. A third approach would be a custom Controller, but this doesn't feel like the Rails way.

To be clear, the combination of {school_id, teacher_id} is globally unique, but the global server need not store details of teachers, those are treated as a web resource.

Comments or suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use rails RESTful architecture on your client apps to expose apis (xml, json), and some library like [Net::HTTP](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) to call those apis from your server(main) app.

Comment: That feels like the right direction to explore.  RESTful apis on the local servers is a given.  I'll look into Net::HTTP.  

At what level should the global /school/42/teacher/3 be parsed?  There needs to be an AR lookup to get Schools.find(42).url and then relay the call to /teacher/3 at that URL.  I'll try a controller to handle unrouted calls on School.  If a set up a route something like
 
    match 'school/:school_id/*resource' => 'SchoolDelegate#delegate' 

and then implement #delegate to use Net::HTTP, am I on the right track?

Comment: You should check out the [REST chapter](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780132480345/rest-resources-and-rails/ch03#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODAxMzI0ODAzNDUvNTU=) of The Rails 3 Way

Comment: I've made some progress... the route that I mentioned above is working, I am implementing a delegate method that has built the correct URI to relay to (looking up the school by id to obtain the correct base) and can now use Net::HTTP.  The next step is to write code that copies the method and body to the HTTP call.  This feels like it should be easier.  Should I be creating get, put, post, delete methods on my delegate and routing to those rather than trying to do it all in a single method?

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it got me past the mental block to the pont where I'm writing code.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Pow](http://pow.cx/) may be what your looking for.  It allows you to configure URL's for stack and rails application via symbolic links.  It fits well in the rails model and may allow you to build your independent RESTful applications in the manor specified.  I know their are methods for having independent rails servers work together but based this is a very low overhead approach and may be the way to go at-least for testing and development purposes.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  Each 'school' will have its own application, with access to local resources, the question is about the implementation of the global app, probably hosted on Heroku.  I'm not sure how Pow assists in this case.  If the school apps were co-located with the global app, it would make more sense to use a single ActiveRecord for 'teachers' and the need for cross-app communication would not arise.

Comment: It allows you to simulate each application with an independent address communicating via REST in your development, it's possible without it but it is a nice developer tool.  As for deployment on Heroku, upon deployment you would update the addresses accordingly.  I do no believe sharing an ActiveRecord across multiple rails applications is possible.  A common database absolutely but single common ActiveRecord across multiple independent rails applications no.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kurt. In this case, a monolithic database is not the right approach, but at some level, it should feel like it is monolithic.  Most of the app will operate within a 'school', but there will be occasional interactions... imagine a teacher visiting a different school.  REST gives me a neat way to describe the resource without referring to a specific implementation.  I still think ActiveResource is the right type of abstraction, but it is based on the assumption of a single fixed resource.  You've taught me something today and I appreciate your input.